# Passing variables from sh to expect not working with docker-compose

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, environment-variables, expect

The Dockerfile contains:

```
ENV VAR 1
COPY ./setup.exp /tmp/
RUN chmod a+x /tmp/setup.exp
```

The expect file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
spawn setup -v
expect "Enter variable: "
send -- "$env(VAR)\r"
```

The shell file (main.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
/tmp/setup.exp $VAR
```

When I run `./main.sh` from the shell inside the container, it works perfectly fine.

However, when I run `docker-compose up` with `entrypoint: ./main.sh`, it prints this error:

```
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send -- "$env(VAR)\r""
    (file "/tmp/setup.exp" line 5)
```

If I pass the variable directly as `entrypoint: /tmp/setup.exp ${VAR}`, it prints this warning:

```
WARNING: The VAR variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

I also tried `set VAR [lindex $argv 0];` and then `send -- "$VAR\r"` without any success.

Seems like from inside the container the script is able to load docker's `env` variables.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "spawn id exp4 not open" means the setup program has already exited.

Comment: That warning `The VAR variable has not been set` means you need to set that environment variable in your current shell environment before running docker-compose. Can you try `export VAR=1` and then re-running `docker-compose up`?

Comment: As I understand it, the syntax is `ENV VAR 1`.

Comment: Yes you are right @meuh the syntax I posted is actually for docker-compose `environment: - VAR=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @glennjackman for pointing that out. I ran `expect -d` for a more verbose output.

It turns out the reason the program exited is because python was raising this exception:

```
ValueError: invalid width 0 (must be > 0)
```

Setting the variable say `ENV COLUMNS 100` in the Dockerfile solved the issue for me.